# A sum-product estimate in Z/pZ

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

There is an exercise in a paper by George Shakan

*George Shakan,* [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://gshakan.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/discretefouriertransform1.pdf)

say that

---

Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ be any set not containing zero with $|A|>\sqrt2q^{5/8}$. Show that:
$$(A+A).(A+A)+A.A+A.A = \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$$
with
$$A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b \in B\}$$
and
$$A.B=\{ab: a\in A, b \in B\}$$

---

so, is there any more ways to expand $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$? And if there is, which key word I can use to find papers of them?

Thanks.

Comment: Representation / decomposition of elements of $Z/pZ$? Another example: if $p$ is prime, every elements of $Z/pZ$ can be written as the sum of two squares.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I mean some other variants of expressions for the left side. For example, in the book of T. Tao and V. Vu "Additive Combinatorics" there is a Lemma:
Let $F$ be a finite field, and let $A$ be a subset of $F$\{0} such that $|A| > |F|^{3/4}$. Then
$3(A.A) = A.A + A.A + A.A = F.$
I want some ways to expand $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ to a function of $A.A$ and $A+A$ like this.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a few results of this type published, although I am struggling to remember where to find them right now.

There is a paper of Glibichuk and Rudnev (here is an [arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.2696.pdf), and here is the [published version](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11854-009-0021-4)) which shows that, for any $A,B \subset \mathbb F_q$
$$
|A||B| \geq q \Rightarrow 10A \cdot B = \mathbb F_q.
$$
Here $10A \cdot B=A\cdot B+A\cdot B+\dots+A\cdot B$, as in your comment above. I am pretty sure there is a paper of Iosevich and Rudnev (and possibly other authors) which proves that
$$
|A| \gg q^{3/4} \Rightarrow AA+AA=\mathbb F_q.
$$
Or something close to this statement. Perhaps someone else will be able to dig out the reference.

In Theorem 30 of [this long paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.01003.pdf), it was proven that, for $A \subset \mathbb F_p$ with $p$ prime,
$$
|A| \gg p^{3/5} \Rightarrow (A-A)(A-A)(A-A)(A-A)= \mathbb F_p.
$$

I think there are many other variants of these kinds of results out there. A related and somewhat easier question is to consider the threshold for which these expanders are guaranteed to generate a positive proportion of the elements of the finite field. But this answer is already too long.